# Access object properties inside another object

Tags: javascript, object, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I´m new to Firebase and I want to access the 'name' and 'score' properties. How could I do this?

Here is the db-structure:
[image]

I get the whole database like this(following [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)), but I dont knwo how I could access the properties of the objects(for example the name of '-Kk50CJUCI...') inside.

```
scores.on('value', getData, errData)

function getData(data) {
    console.log(data.val())
}

function errData (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a `child_added` event listener, you will get each child node (-Kk50CJUCI.. etc.) individually. You can then directly access the child properties of the `data.val()` as below:

```
scores.on('child_added', getData, errData)

function getData(data) {
    console.log(data.val().name)
    console.log(data.val().score)
}

function errData (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bradley!